# Add float to Java Calendar

Tags: java

I'm currently developing some functionality that needs to either subtract or add  time to a Calendar class instance. The time I need to add/sub is in a properties file and could be any of these formats:

> 30,sec
>
> 90,sec
>
> 1.5,min
>
> 2,day
>
> 2.333,day

Let's assume addition for simplicity. I would read those values in a String array:

```
String[] propertyValues = "30,sec".split(",");
```

I would read the second value in that comma-separated pair, and map that to the relevant int in the Calendar class (so for example, "sec" becomes Calendar.SECOND, "min" becomes Calendar.MINUTE):

```
int calendarMajorModifier = mapToCalendarClassIntValues(propertyValues[1]);
```

To then do the actual operation I would do it as simple as:

```
cal.add(calendarMajorModifier, Integer.parseInt(propertyValues[0]));
```

This works and it's not overly complicated. The issue is now floating values (so 2.333,day for eaxmple) - how would you deal with it?

```
String[] propertyValues = "2.333,day".split(",");
```

As you can imagine the code becomes quite hairy (I haven't actually written it yet, so please ignore syntax mistakes)

```
float timeComponent = Float.parseFloat(propertyValues[0]);
if (calendarMajorModifier == Calendar.DATE) {
    int dayValue = Integer.parseFloat(timeComponent);
    cal.add(calendarMajorModifier, dayValue);
    timeComponent = (timeComponent - dayValue) * 24; //Need to convert a fraction of a day to hours
    if (timeComponent != 0) {
        calendarMajorModifier = Calendar.HOUR;
    }
}
if (calendarMajorModifier == Calendar.HOUR) {
    int hourValue = Integer.parseFloat(timeComponent);
    cal.add(calendarMajorModifier, hourValue);
    timeComponent = (timeComponent - hourValue) * 60; //Need to convert a fraction of an hour to minutes
    if (timeComponent != 0) {
        calendarMajorModifier = Calendar.MINUTE;
    }
}
... etc
```

Granted, I can see how there may be a refactoring opportunity, but still seems like a very brute-forceish solution.

I am using the Calendar class to do the operations on but could technically be any class. As long as I can convert between them (i.e. by getting the long value and using that), as the function *needs* to return a Calendar class. Ideally the class also has to be Java native to avoid third party licensing issues :).

Side note: I suggested changing the format to something like yy:MM:ww:dd:hh:mm:ss to avoid floating values but that didn't pan out. I also suggested something like 2,day,5,hour, but again, ideally needs to be format above.

Comment: I suggest you use the Java Time API. `Calendar` is outdated. Also, to deal with arbitrary-precision decimal values, I suggest to look at the `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: It could be a `List<Adjustment>` and each is applied to `cal` (or some other type of object).  A property entry of `2,day` has only 1 item in the list, while  `2.333,day` has two items in the list.  And separate parsing of the property value from applying the adjustment(s).

Comment: You'd need to code transitions yourself (do consider working `java.time` library instead of calendar though) - there isn't really a "fraction" to any of our time units - when we're saying "a day and a half", what we actually mean is "1 day, 12 hours". That conversion is usually not represented by any datetime library due to how arbitrary it really is.

Comment: I'll have a look at the Time class and see if that can help make it simpler - at the end of the day, the output still has to be a Calendar class, regardless of what is outdated or not.
And Indeed Prokhorov, I am not too fond of the format either as you run into these silly calculations, unfortunately I don't have final decision :)

Comment: @Martin, essentially what you do is you split away the integer part of whatever unit you have. Then you take next smallest unit, and take the integer part of that unit, and so on (you will need to also make an ordered structure of units here). As a result of this parsing, you should then get from the `2.333 days` something close to `2 days 7 hours 59 minutes 31 seconds 2 centiseconds` exactly (given that the input is `2.333` and it's not an exact third of the day). To make this less strict, you might want to, say, round minutes to hours if you received input in days, etc.

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to allow your users to enter time periods with as many fields as they need to keep values of all fields as integers. But that's out of this question, I assume.

Answer (score 4):

I'd transform the value into the smallest unit and add that:

```
float timeComponent = Float.parseFloat(propertyValues[0]);
int unitFactor = mapUnitToFactor(propertyValues[1]);
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int)(timeComponent * unitFactor));
```

and `mapUnitToFactor` would be something like:

```
int mapUnitToFactor(String unit)
{
    if ("sec".equals(unit))
        return 1;
    if ("min".equals(unit))
        return 60;
    if ("hour".equals(unit))
        return 3600;
    if ("day".equals(unit))
        return 24*3600;
    throw new InvalidParameterException("Unknown unit: " + unit);
}
```

So for example 2.333 days would be turned into 201571 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did consider a similar function as it's relatively clean, and was half way implementing that until there were talks about also having "1,month" as a valid property value which would ruin that implementation, unfortunately. 
But I may be able to convince them floating values for a month are hard to calculate and therefore only allow integer values for the month.

Comment: Not every day has 86400 seconds in it. To keep is at true to the source as possible, it's best to keep periods as coarse as possible.

Comment: @Martin Yeah, floating point for a month makes no sense. To be able to implement that (no matter how), you would have to specify a fixed size for interpreting the fraction of a month. But that's just a disaster waiting to happen. And as @ M.Prokhorov pointed out, this is even true for days (and thus weeks), although depending on how accurate you want this to be, a leap second might not be that much of an issue (otherwise you shouldn't be using floats anyways).